# Format text with a timezone

Tags: java, android, date-formatting

I am parsing date and time information and then setting my TextView's text with a formatted version of the information.

The problem I am having is the the time is set to the timezone of my device. I would like the formatted text to be in the original timezone from the Event.getDateTime() String which contains timezone information. I seem to be missing something since the timezone information is no longer stored in the Date object. How can I format my text with the original timezone?

I don't need to display the original timezone in my TextView, just have the time set to it.

```
private void onProcessDateTime(TextView content3, Card item, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final Event event = ((EventCard) item).getEvent();
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    Date date = null;
    SimpleDateFormat parse = null;
    DateFormat format = null;
    if (event.getDateTime() != null 
            && !event.getDateTime().equals("null"))
    {
        parse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", locale);
        try
        {
            date = parse.parse(event.getDateTime());

        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        format = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance
                (DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
    }
...
    content3.setText(format.format(date));
}
```

Comment: I use :  dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

Answer (score 0):

Trying to store and recreate local times is a heap of trouble. Far better to `Store globally, Present locally`. When you get a date-time, immediately convert to UTC. Work in UTC, and store in UTC. Convert to time zones only as necessary or upon presentation to the user.

If you must serialize a date-time to text, do so in a clean standard way. Usually that means [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

And obtain a decent date-time library such as [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new JSR 310 java.time.* in Java 8. Some folks use Joda-Time in Android. I've not done so, therefore I can't verify if the code works on that platform.

Here's some Joda-Time example source code. Joda-Time 2.3 in Java 7 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

### From DateTime to String

```java
// Capture the current moment.
// The no-arg constructor automatically uses the user's default (and presumably local) time zone.
org.joda.time.DateTime nowInDefaultTimeZone = new org.joda.time.DateTime();
// Convert to UTC.
org.joda.time.DateTime nowPutInUtc = nowInDefaultTimeZone.toDateTime( org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.UTC );
// Or, if you don't need local time zone, create instance in UTC.
org.joda.time.DateTime now = new org.joda.time.DateTime( org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.UTC );

// Joda-Time by default converts to a String by using an ISO 8601 formatter.
String nowAsString = now.toString();
```

### From String To DateTime

```java
// Pretend we read that string from storage. Reconstitute a DateTime.

// Use the built-in ISO 8601 formatter to parse string.
// ISODateTimeFormat is automatically set to user's own time zone.
// By the way, you may obtain that time zone explicitly: org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getDefault()
org.joda.time.DateTime nowReconstitutedInUserTimeZone = org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime( nowAsString );

// Create string to present to user.
// 'forStyle' uses a two-character pattern.
// The first character is the date style, and the second character is the time style.
// Specify a character of 'S' for short style, 'M' for medium, 'L' for long, and 'F' for full.
// A date or time may be omitted by specifying a style character '-'.
org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "MS" );
String nowAsStringAgain = nowReconstitutedInUserTimeZone.toString( formatter );

// Back to UTC if you need it.
org.joda.time.DateTime nowReconstitutedAndConvertToInUtc = nowReconstitutedInUserTimeZone.toDateTime( org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.UTC );

// Or reconstitute directly into UTC.
org.joda.time.DateTime nowReconstitutedInUtc = org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZoneUTC().parseDateTime( nowAsString );
```

### Output to Console

```
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "nowReconstitutedInUserTimeZone: " + nowReconstitutedInUserTimeZone );
System.out.println( "nowReconstitutedAndConvertToInUtc: " + nowReconstitutedAndConvertToInUtc );
System.out.println( "nowReconstitutedInUtc: " + nowReconstitutedInUtc );
System.out.println( "nowAsStringAgain: " + nowAsStringAgain );
```

When run in Seattle US…

```
now: 2013-11-26T02:54:21.299Z
nowReconstitutedInUserTimeZone: 2013-11-25T18:54:21.299-08:00
nowReconstitutedAndConvertToInUtc: 2013-11-26T02:54:21.299Z
nowReconstitutedInUtc: 2013-11-26T02:54:21.299Z
nowAsStringAgain: Nov 25, 2013 6:54 PM
```

---

Actually, the best way to store date-times is as date-times such as in a date-time savvy database like [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html). For the sake of this question I assumed we were forced to serialize a date-time as text.

Comment: Thanks and I will consider that library, but I still don't see a way to read the timezone from the event.getDateTime() String (which is in the "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ") format and then reconstitute it in a more displayable fasion, using the timezone in that String, not in the user's local timezone. I don't need to store anything, just basically trying to reformat the String.

Comment: @svenoaks The string format you specified happens to be ISO 8601 format, Joda-Time's default calendaring system. My answer gives you the lines of code you need to interpret such a string into a DateTime while assigning user's default time zone (`nowReconstitutedInUserTimeZone`). And my answer gives you code to create a string representation of that DateTime in Medium date + Short time format as you asked (`nowAsStringAgain`). What is missing that you need? As for storage, if you are not storing, why else would `event.getDateTime()` return a String – why not return an actual DateTime object?

Comment: Upon rereading your question, I see you want to go back to original time zone when the date-time was captured. Experienced programmers recommending (almost) always converting the date-time to UTC. But if the original time zone matters, keep that *also*. You can store the date-time as a string in ISO 8601 format that includes an offset. But you should instead (or also) store the time zone in use at the time. My answer shows you both: `toString` and `DateTimeZone.getDefault`.